# When Passing from one viewcontroller to another the view moves up x pixels

Tags: iphone, view, uiview, uiviewcontroller

When I at first run the app my view shows perfectly but when  I "pushViewController" (the same one)
the view moves up maybe something like 60 pixels.

What can be the problem?

With this function I push the viewController:

```
-(void)userLogin
{
MSLoginViewController *loginController = [[MSLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MSLoginViewController" bundle:nil];
loginController.isTryToBuyCoupon = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:loginController animated:YES];
[loginController release];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to give more info, code, maybe screenshots.

Comment: push what from where? little code would be nice

Comment: I added to first message my code example

Answer (score 0):

You might have set YES for setNavigationBarHidden method. This will cause your view to move up by 44 px. More detail about your problem will make us easy to answer.